# I am the first. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am the first.
>
> I am in apple.
>
> I am a language.
>
> I am there in above lines, of course here also.
>
> Beginners prefer me.

**Who am I?**

**HINT1**

> Each line above gives each letter, and the whole word is the final answer

**HINT2**

> We are twelve and I am the fourth one

**HINT3**

> Beginners prefer me.I think this line make little confusion. It is related to vehicle, driver etc

Now I think the puzzle more easy..

Comment: hey man. i must have the right answer!? Good work.

Comment: This is a fair first try. Try going through [the Riddle Sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox?cb=1) to learn about what exactly is a good riddle.

Comment: "*Who am I? None of your business!*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> **April**

1. I am the first

> **A** is the first letter

2. I am in apple

> **P** is in apple

3. I am a language

> The language [**R**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language))

4. I am there in above lines, of course here also

> The letter **I** exists in all the above lines

5. Beginners prefer me

> New drivers drive under [**L-board**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-plate)

*The second hint made it too easy though...*

Comment: Yes you are right. Since the questions is too broad, i added the hits, I know that makes the puzzle too easy..

Comment: @DeepuSasidharan should try 1 hint at a time! see how many hints it takes for puzzlers to get it :)

Answer (score 21):

You are

> The letter **a**

I am the first.

> **a** is the first letter in the English alphabet.

I am in apple.

> **a** is indeed in 'apple'

I am a language.

> [A+ is a programming language descendant from the programming language **A**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2B_(programming_language))

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> The letter **a** is present in every line above, including this one.

Beginners prefer me.

> If you are new to something, you would gladly prefer the letter grade **A** over anything else.

Comment: That was my first guess too, but since he put the "word" tag in,  I think the "letter" a might be wrong :)

Comment: good attempt,on the track, but not I am thinking

Comment: The reasoning behind "I am in apple" and "I am in language" could be the same.

Comment: Was thinking APL (a programming language) but no way beginners would prefer it over a different language

Comment: @Foitn -- 'A' is a word in the English dictionary.  From your smiley, I assume you are nitpicking A.B's choice of "letter" over "word" in his answer?

Comment: @A.B., hints are available now the puzzle is more easy..+1 for your good attempt

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps sure, you can call it nitpicking, but an answer has to be completely correct, right? Maybe because I gave this comment he could have found a flaw, repaired his answer and have the correct one anyways...

Answer (score 12):

Are you

> HTML

```
I am the first.
```

> 

```
I am in apple.
```

> Apple is using html codes in their website

```
I am a language.
```

> HTML is a Markup language

```
I am there in above lines, of course here also.
```

> This site uses HTML codes

```
Beginners prefer me.
```

> Beginners prefer learning HTML as a start to programming

Comment: HTML? Programming? Haha!... Jokes aside- HTML is a markup language, not programming. Also, the second spoiler is not revealable so maybe fix that.

Comment: @IIRawCodeII I mean, the clue only says "I am a language," and HTM**L** is certainly a **language**, regardless of the programming vs. markup distinction.

Comment: Not the correct answer, +1

Answer (score 12):

> The letter i

I am the first.

> I is 1 in roman numerals

I am in apple.

> It is at the start of (almost?) all the names of Apple's products. (iPod, iMac...)

I am a language.

> “I” language is a great way for a person to express his/her point of view without putting the other person on the defensive. (source: www.wikihow.com)

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> The letter i is used in every line.

Beginners prefer me.

> Beginners in english will often use "me" istead of "I" in sentence like, "My brother and me..." -> "My brother and I..."

> At first I thought it was the capital letter "I" but it's not true for the names of Apple's products.

Comment: I is also the "first person" point of view :D

Comment: I like this answer a **lot**, though I'm not sure how well "I am a language" fits. You can add a link to your WikiHow reference using this format: `[link text](https://example.com/example)`

Comment: +1 for the clever interpretation of _beginners prefer me_

Comment: Good attempt, +1 .Hints added edited..

Answer (score 8):

are you

> seed

I am the first.

> seeds come before plants

I am in apple.

> apples have seeds

I am a language.

> a [programming language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed)

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> possibly referring to how farmers sow land in lines with seeds?

Beginners prefer me.

> 

Comment: I like the answer, but not the one I am thinking,+1. Hints are available for the question

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Adam

I am the first.

> First human, or first prophet according to Islam

I am in apple

> Adam's apple

I am a language

> Adamic language (language spoken by Adam)

I am there in above lines, of course here also

> I have no idea about this one

Beginners prefer me

> One of the first religious stories people learn

Comment: Not the correct answer,+1. please see the hints

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> C

I am the first.

> C was the precursor to pretty much all of the most widely used programming languages today. Some like C++ and Objective-C are built on top of C and the C compiler, while others like Java are separate but use similar syntax.

I am in apple.

> Apple's software is all built on C as far as I know (Swift and Objective-C are both built on top of C).

I am a language.

> C is a programming language.

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> C is in things from the previous lines: Apple, programming languages, etc. and the letter C is also in this line, in the phrase "of course".

Beginners prefer me.

> C is one of the first languages any new programmer should learn and is taught at some point in just about every Computer Science curriculum. It is up for debate whether beginners actually prefer C or are forced to learn it for their own good, but for a lot of programmers these days it reminds them of college classes when they were first learning data structures, operating systems, etc.

Comment: Good one +1, Hints are available for the question

Comment: [C was not the first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages). It's even called C because it came after A and B.

Answer (score 2):

Are you,

> The alphabet or letters?

I am the first.

> It is the start of learning the English language.

I am in apple.

> The word *apple* contains letters of the alphabet.

I am a language.

> Again, it is the alphabet for the English language.

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> Letters are in this sentence and in the sentences above.

Beginners prefer me.

> Kids learn the letters of the alphabet before learning to read!

Answer (score 2):

You're

> SWIFT! :D

how do i do those yellow boxes? Nvm got it.

You are

> SWIFT

I am the first.

> swift is speedy

I am in apple.

> devices i'm in.

I am a language.

> ya programming language

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> first apple language

Beginners prefer me.

> SWIFT for noobs

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> dot (.)

I am the first.

> First dot in the riddle

I am in apple.

> Technically in it, since each character is made of dots

I am a language.

> DOT is a graph description language

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> In every line

Beginners prefer me.

> . = 1, when beginners learn to count, .. = 2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

You are

> a space/whitespace

I am the first.

> space is the first actual character in the ASCII table

I am in apple.

> I guess there's some empty space in an apple's core?

I am a language.

> There's a whitespace esolang, and also meaningful in Python, but honestly this part seems like a stretch because "space is not a language". However [OP said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62237/who-am-i-my-first-puzzle/62286#comment189843_62240) the other answer is very close.

I am there in above lines, of course here also.

> Every line has a space

Beginners prefer me.

> "Beginners like to have space"?